# Dynamic Casting based on Type information

Tags: c#, casting

I want to do an explicit cast using Type information from one array to another which is related by inheritance. My problem is that while casting using Type information  the compiler throws error, but my requirement is to dynamically cast based on the Type information provided.

Please Help

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Parent[] objParent;
        Child[] objChild = new Child[] { new Child(), new Child() };
        Type TypParent = typeof(Parent);

        //Works when i mention the class name
        objParent = (Parent[])objChild;

        //Doesn't work if I mention Type info 
        objParent = (TypParent[])objChild;
    }
}

class Parent
{
}

class Child : Parent
{
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only way you can cast dynamically is with reflection. Of course you can't cast `objChild` to `TypParent[]` - you are trying to cast an array of `Child` to an array of `Type`.

You could use the `.Cast<T>()` method called with reflection to achieve this:

```
 MethodInfo castMethod = this.GetType().GetMethod("Cast").MakeGenericMethod(typeParent);
 object castedObject = castMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { objChild });
```

If you need one for non-IEnumerable types, make an extension/static method:

```
public static T Cast<T>(this object o)
{
    return (T)o;
}
```